# EE3 where did multi-edit go?

Tags: control-panel, ee3

Ok, now that I've updated several sites to EE 3, I noticed that I can't find the multi entry edit function anymore. Has it been removed? I read somewhere that it was still there, but I can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk adding/removing of categories and changing of statuses is indeed gone in EE3. All you can do in bulk is delete entries.

I suggest making a [feature request](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewforum/136/) for this!